# Indicator Random Variable coin flip pairs problem

Tags: probability, random-variables

"Use indicator random variables to solve this problem.
What is the expected number of pairs of heads in ten flips of a fair coin? (For example, if the result of the ten flips is HTHHTTHHHH, there are four pairs of heads)."

Greetings everyone, thanks for reading.

Here is my work so far:

$I_k :$ random variable of the outcome of the $k^{th}$ flip.

$I_k = ${0,1} where P(0) = 1/2 = P(1)

1. $E(I_k) = 0*1/2 + 1*1/2 = 1/2$
2. E($I_1 + I_2 + ... + I_{10}) = 5$

Note: I didn't really have a feel for the entire solution so I simply calculated the expected number of heads

At this point, I was thinking of calculating the number of pairs for the expected number of heads, that is, 5. However, I didn't think this would work because, often, the expected value is a decimal value. For example, imagine calculating the number of pairs for 5.5 heads.

I have a feeling that I misdefined my random variable.

Question: How should I define the variable $I_k$ ?

Answer: 2.25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$X_i=1$$ if the tosses nr. $\ i\ $ and $\ i+1\ $ are both heads and $\ 0\ $ otherwise , where $\ i=1,\cdots ,9$

Then, we have $$E(X_i)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1+\frac{3}{4}\cdot 0=\frac{1}{4}$$ for $\ i=1,\cdots, 9\ $ hence the expected number of pairs is $$E(X_1+\cdots +X_9)=E(X_1)+\cdots +E(X_9)=9\cdot \frac{1}{4}=2.25$$

Comment: Amazing solution, thank you.